# Is $[0, 2 \pi) $compact?

Tags: analysis

I have to make a exercise about metric spaces and this was a question.

"Consider $A = [0, 2 \pi)$ with the usual metric, is $A$ compact?

Comment: What is your definition of "compact"?

Comment: It's not. The sequence $2 \pi - 1/n$ does not converge insisde that set.

Comment: Is the set $A$ closed?

Comment: @Dave Do you mean "complete"? "Closed" is a relative term, a property of _subsets_, so if we ask that, we need to know what $A$ is contained in. It could be $A\subseteq(-2\pi, 2\pi)$ for all we know, and in that case, the answer is "Yes, $A$ is closed, but it doesn't help us any".

Comment: @Arthur good point, I assumed this was just in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Dave Quite a natural assumption to make without any further context, I'll admit. But an assumption nonetheless.

Comment: Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the metric space equipped with the Euclidean metric. Then one important theorem for determining which subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact is the [Heine–Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). It says a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $A_n = \left[0,2\pi-\frac 1 n\right)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Each $A_n$ is open in $[0, 2\pi)$, and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n = A$, but no finite collection of $A_i$'s covers $A$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no finite sub-cover of the open cover $\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,2\pi)}[0,\alpha)$